# How to initialize the new object in S4 class?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I have data as like the following:

```
data = data.frame( id = rbinom(1000, 10, .75),
            visit = sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE),
            room = sample(letters[1:5], 1000, replace = TRUE),
            value = rnorm(1000, 50, 10),
            timepoint = abs(rnorm(1000))
)
head(data)
id visit room    value  timepoint
1  8     3    a 62.53394 1.64681140
2  9     1    c 53.67313 1.04093204
3  6     1    c 64.96674 0.40599449
4  8     2    d 41.04145 0.09911475
5  7     2    b 63.86938 1.01732424
6  7     3    c 42.03524 2.04128413
```

I have defined a S4 class to read this data as `longitudinalData`. The class goes as follows.

```
setClass("longitudinalData",
         slots = list(id = "integer", 
                      visit = "integer",
                      room = "character",
                      value = "numeric",
                      timepoint = 'numeric'))
```

To initiate a new object in this class I have defined the following function.

```
make_LD = function(x){
new("longitudinalData",
          id = x$id,
          visit = x$visit,
          room = x$room,
          value = x$value,
          timepoint = x$timepoint
  )
}
```

when I try add a new object by `make_LD(data)` I get the following error.

```
> make_LD(data)
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  no slot of name "refMethods" for this object of class "classRepresentation"
```

### What does this error means?

### How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid these sorts of problems is to save the value from `setClass`, which returns a handy constructor function for you to use.

```
setClass("longitudinalData",
         slots = list(id = "integer", 
                      visit = "integer",
                      room = "character",
                      value = "numeric",
                      timepoint = 'numeric')) -> longitudinalData

make_LD = function(x){
longitudinalData(
          id = x$id,
          visit = x$visit,
          room = x$room,
          value = x$value,
          timepoint = x$timepoint
  )
}
```

It is normal to give the constructor function the same name as the class, but you don't have to.